# Tensorflow histogram with custom bins

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have two tensors - one with bin specification and the other one with observed values. I'd like to count how many values are in each bin.
I know how to do this in either NumPy or bare Python, but I need to do this in *pure TensorFlow*. Is there a more sophisticated version of `tf.histogram_fixed_width` with an argument for bin specification?

Example:

```
# Input - 3 bins and 2 observed values
bin_spec = [0, 0.5, 1, 2]
values = [0.1, 1.1]
# Histogram
[1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, although I consider it to be quite memory- and time-consuming.

```
import tensorflow as tf

bins = [-1000, 1, 3, 10000]
vals = [-3, 0, 2, 4, 5, 10, 12]

vals = tf.constant(vals, dtype=tf.float64, name="values")
bins = tf.constant(bins, dtype=tf.float64, name="bins")

resh_bins = tf.reshape(bins, shape=(-1, 1), name="bins-reshaped")
resh_vals = tf.reshape(vals, shape=(1, -1), name="values-reshaped")

left_bin = tf.less_equal(resh_bins, resh_vals, name="left-edge")
right_bin = tf.greater(resh_bins, resh_vals, name="right-edge")

resu = tf.logical_and(left_bin[:-1, :], right_bin[1:, :], name="bool-bins")
counts = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(resu), axis=1, name="count-in-bins")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(counts))
```